# Can you use Shiba Tokens/wBTC ERC20 Tokens in smart contract?

Tags: contract-development, erc-20, contract-design, metamask, ethers.js

I'm building a bounty Dapp that uses MetaMask. This app works with multiple chains (IE BSC, Ethereum, Polygon, AVAX). I want to give users the ability to use Shiba Inu Token/wBTC/wDOGE/any token on any chain when creating a bounty. Is this possible ? If so, is there documentation?

Thanks!

Comment: Hello. Your question is way too broad. Your question should focus on one problem and not be something like "how do I modelize my project". Good luck.

Comment: In any chain you only can use tokens of that platform. Some tokens are available in multiple chains because there's someone maintaining a bridge that can move tokens between different chains. Anyone can create a bridge, but it has its own complications.